# Can i embed videos other than youtube in blogger?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, embed, blogger, blogspot

Can I embed videos other than youtube in blogger? For example can I embed mp4upload videos or yourupload videos?

```
<iframe src="http://www.yourupload.com/embed/f0PN56si4NJy" width="640" height="360" allowfullscreen><iframe>
```

I used this embed code but I'm unable to play it in blogspot.

Answer (score 1):

Blogger only allow ***https*** links for `<iframe>` sources.

This `<iframe>` should do what you try to do *(I tested this )* :

```
<iframe src="https://www.yourupload.com/embed/f0PN56si4NJy" width="640" height="360" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Live test [here](https://stackfun.blogspot.de/2017/01/can-i-embed-videos-other-than-youtube.html).

Comment: this is a tested iframe source. You can test it in any browser

Answer (score 0):

I'used this iframe and is working for me into an html/javascript widget

```
<iframe src="http://www.yourupload.com/embed/f0PN56si4NJy" allowfullscreen="true" style="border: 0" /></iframe>
```